# Navigation Drawer below Tool bar in Material Design

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I want my drawer to open from the left below the tool bar. But, according to Material Design aspects that's not good. But still I want to do that.

Here I have changed my XML file. 
---Relative Layout 
-----Tool bar  
-----Drawer  
-------container 
-------drawer List

here is my XML file. My app crashes when it opens. I don't know where I made a mistake and XML doesn't show any errors.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.myApp.activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: App crashes when you open the drawer or start the application itself? Anyway you should post log so anyone can help you..

Comment: App crashes on start. Not showing any specific error.

Comment: Post logcat to see where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the latest solution for material design

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!--content_main is my layout you can design your own-->
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Don't use this, this is wrong as per Android guidelines

Comment: @ShirishHerwade Why? Please explain or reference your statement.

Answer (score 8):

I have created New XML file **main_activity_appbar** and added tool bar first and in same layout file I added my Drawer Layout. and in **mainAcitity.java** file I changed layout of that file.

**main_activity_appbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.myApp.activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);
```

This is working fine.

Comment: how about having a button to open the drawerlayout. this is where iam having issues!!