# How to put navigation drawer below toolbar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

Here my navigation drawer is above toolbar.I also added some xml code.Please help me.

[image: Here my navigation drawer is above toolbar]

here is my activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and my app_bar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ezybzy.ezybzy.categoris">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_categoris" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and my content main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ezybzy.ezybzy.categoris"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_categories"
    android:background="#ffffff">
</RelativeLayout>
```

I created the navigation drawer using android studios navigation drawer activity..

Comment: you can refer to this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059761/navigation-drawer-below-tool-bar-in-material-design

Comment: see this site It will help you to make code http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

certainly `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` do the job in

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

But the problem is drawerlayout is top of the toolbar. That is why the fading here.
you can remove fading by

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

But on some devices it may look wired.

### Solution

When working with Android studio. We can create `NavigationDrawerActiviity`
There are 3 files named

> activity_main.xml
>
> app_bar_main.xml
>
> nav_header_main.xml
>
> content_main.xml

So we can skip `app_bar_main.xml` and we can remove the fading.

#### Step 1

Make the root view of the activity main as Vertical `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
</LinearLayout>
```

In `activity_main.xml` add `DrawerLayout` and include `content_main.xml` in `DrawerLayout`. and Add `AppBarLayout` above the `DrawerLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.qproinnovations.schoolmanagement.activity.HomeActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
    <!-- drawer view -->
        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
<!-- drawer content -->
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Step 2

add and replace `setContentView()` of NavigationDrawerActiviity to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Finally we have

[image]

Comment: Lifesaver.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Add

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

to your layout which you are using as drawer.

Comment: its working when i added this in navigation view.But when the navigation drawer comes action bar is fading..I don't want this fading.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar) to remove actionbar fading.

Comment: This along with setting android:fitsSystemWindows to "false" for the DrawerLayout worked for me in terms of getting the drawer to be below the toolbar.

Comment: @ProgDevCode happy to helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In your navigation drawer xml you should add `android:layout_marginTop ="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` to the container.

Comment: But when the navigation drawer comes action bar is fading..I don't want this action bar fading

Answer (score 2):

If you are using custom toolbar then use the drawer layout in this way..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- drawer view -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start">
            ....
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and if you are not using custom toolbar then you have to set margin top to the drawer layout..

```
android:layout_marginTop ="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Answer (score 2):

An Easy and Good solution is set `fitsSystemWindows=false` for

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

that has id as

```
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
```

And for `navigationView` set `layout_marginTop` as `?attr/actionBarSize` that would get the actionbar size and set it as margin

Here is complete `activity_main.xml` code that has both the changes listed above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    <!--app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: beacuse the whole layout will fade when opening navigation drawer

Comment: The correct way is to fade only the overlapping portion of the layout

Comment: this is not because of the changes I applied in the above code. Its default behavior of DrawerLayout

Comment: but it can be achieved by the answer of this question

Comment: If you want no fading use a scrim color
`mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.transparent));`

Comment: then all fading will be lost it has no effect when opening navigation drawer

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout like this:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >
            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                />


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_new">


    <put your layout here................>

            </FrameLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_all"

            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:theme="@style/list_item_appearance"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" >


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your drawer covering your toolbar,to avoid that try below code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/toolBarStyle"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            class="com.buzzintown.consumer.drawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            tools:layout="@layout/drawer_layout" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!--content_main is my layout you can design your own-->
   <!--one more thing is dont put toolbar in your content_main layout-->
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use can change the  navigation drawer xml `android:layout_marginTop ="0dp"` set the top margin in toolbar

Comment: But when the navigation drawer comes action bar is fading..I don't want this fading..