# Put Navigation Drawer below Toolbar and above TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout containing a Navigation Drawer, a Toolbar and a Tablayout with ViewPager. I'd like to put the Navigation Drawer below the Toolbar and above the TabLayout to see the transition animation of hamburger menu.

Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     tools:openDrawer="start"
     tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: these should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810384/how-to-put-navigation-drawer-below-toolbar?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985270/navigation-drawer-below-toolbar?rq=1

Comment: Put your Toolbar above appBarLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `DrawerLayout` as root Create `RelativeLayout` as root and put `DrawerLayout` below `Toolbar` inside `RelativLayout` something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/vp_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
                app:pstsTabTextColor="@drawable/switcher_indicator_text_selector"
                app:pstsTabTextSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
                app:pstsUnderlineColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:pstsUnderlineHeight="2dp" />


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/vp_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <include layout="@layout/include_navigation_view" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```